# Installing Ubuntu-20.04.1 on MacOS Mojave with flash drive

Tags: macos, ubuntu, iso-image, macos-mojave, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having an issue with downloading Ubuntu 20.04.1 onto my MacOS Mojave. I followed everything directly from the Ubuntu website, but for some reason, the iso file that they have is corrupted and won't open. I am following these instructions from the Ubuntu website step by step, and am using a flash drive to do so: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#5-etcher-configuration
When I get to the fifth step and "flash" is running on balenaEtcher, I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpZo4.png), which states that the iso file may be corrupted. I'm not sure why I might be getting this error since I am downloading the Ubuntu ISO directly from their website. If anyone has any insight, or needs more info on my issue, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: try turning off SIP.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SIP will likely allow you to use the ISO,

(link to great instructions)
https://www.kadalin.com/how-to-disable-sip-system-integrity-protection-in-macos/

- Turn Off Mac (Shutdown)
- Press and Hold – Command + R + Power Button
- Wait until the Apple Logo shows up Afterward, you will enter the OS X Boot Utilities
  Recovery
- click the Utilities menu > Terminal
- Input “csrutil disable” command to turn OFF SIP (without ")

Repeat steps above with “csrutil enable” command to turn back on SIP

---

Or you can run etcher with sudo from at terminal
sudo /Applications/balenaEtcher.app/Contents/MacOS/balenaEtcher

---

lastly you could just us dd (nick name disk destroyer) to write to the USB directly with terminal.  I won't give instructions on this because as the nick name states, it does have the power to destroy stuff, I myself have wiped my entire OS using it.